# Minio on Symfony

Tags: symfony, minio

So one of my colleagues recommended me to use Minio as my File Storage.

I research about it but there is not enough resources on the net to keep me going. I found KNPGaufretteBundle which has Amazon S3 Adapter. Minio is compatible with Amazon S3, so can I use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Flysystem is the main PHP filesystem abstraction and their S3 driver also works with Digital Ocean's Spaces, which are API compatible with S3, so I would look at that. Flysystem has integrations for most frameworks.

Comment: I run minio using docker, now when I tried to upload, it say that my bucket dosent exist, well in fact i created it on minio browser. Is there a way I can specify the host?

Answer (score 0):

[`aws-sdk-php`](https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-php-with-minio-server) works fine with minio so you should be able to use KNPGaufretteBundle with minio.

You can also look at [laralvel](https://github.com/minio/cookbook/blob/master/docs/how-to-use-minio-as-laravel-file-storage.md) support as well.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous projects I used [flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/aws-s3-v3/) package that has many adapters, including S3. This is best I think because it adds to your source code nice abstraction layer.